# Why a machine running Java app is almost out of physical memory, but still runs for weeks

Tags: java, performance

I have a Java application that is deployed on two machines and judging by metrics (including JMC) they both almost out of memory and it lasts pretty long time. However, the apps run ok and no OutOfMemory errors happen.
[image]

This is confusing. Can you explain why the apps still run not having OutOfMemory error? Why memory doesn't get freed earlier than when it so close to the limit?

PS here is the heap metrics

[image]

Comment: What is your application doing? If it is working through a lot of data, all the time, then it will just use that much memory all the time. Are you opening resources? Do you close them correctly?

Comment: What are the configuration for allocated memory for JVM? If it is close to the values you see here than it is normal, because the GC don't clear the memory after you don't use it - it is passing some time. Especially if you work with a lot of data.

Comment: @Lino this is a backend for data storage for a million of users. It caches, maps data and forwards requests to another services. I'm not completely aware of resources that it opens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just how Java's memory management works - it basically delays garbage collection until necessary in hopes that the application will exit before the GC is needed.

So it will often opt to allocate more memory from the OS, up until a limit either given by `-Xmx` or by OS / total RAM limit, and only then it will perform major garbage collector runs. These runs will free some memory and then the application will run for some more time, until encountering the limit once again.

If the application needs gradually more memory, then what happens after it hits the memory limit is that the major GC runs will get more and more frequent (as the needed memory increases, and memory cleared by GC decreases) and the GC runs will become longer. At some point, the VM may start spending more time in GC than running the application.

In this way, it is possible that the Java process will run for a long time (possibly "forever") and consume almost all available memory, while the actual application gets almost no actual run time due to almost all CPU time being spent in GC. Java may detect this situation and throw a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` with message `GC Overhead Limit Exceeded`, but not always does.

---

If you want to diagnose whether your app is just optimizing memory use, or is actually essentially out of memory, you need to find out how much time VM spends in GC, and what the trend is. Some possible ways:

- Connect with a JConsole or VisualVM (both are parts of the JDK) and check the GC runs (intervals and durations)
- An easier way if your Java application is single-hreaded is to observe CPU load - the default GC is multi-threaded, so during GC run it will mostly run on more processors / cores and the CPU load will be more than 100% of a single core (>100% in unix `top`), while a single-thread application only causes loads up to 100% of a single core.

Comment: In other words, if the situation was critical, I'd get out of memory a long time ago already OR my app would perform really slow?

Comment: This one has to do something with Java 8, Permanent Generation limit removal. Therefore, permanent generation expands up to the available physical memory to keep app running without issuing OutOfMemoryError. All the Strings and static references stay there, and it could get pretty big by the time.

Comment: @SachithDickwella please note that xmx is 5Gb, while used physical memory is 8.4Gb.

Comment: @kas-kad, That's why I said in Java 8, they removed Permanent Generation limit. Well, Permanent Generation is a part out of the Heap, now without explicit limitation. By -Xmx, you define maximum Heap size. Refer this Doc - https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/presenting-the-permanent-generation.

Comment: @kas-kad Sorry - I misread your comment earlier. You're right, it would either crash on out of memory or run terribly slow. If you see no performance degradation, Java taking the maximum memory available to it is not a sign of a problem. If you want to see how much of a head space you have, use JConsole or VisualVM and look at how much memory is used *as reported by VM, after a major / full GC run*. Looking at OS info is misleading since VM does its own memory management.

Comment: @SachithDickwella are you suggesting to limit the permanent generation size?

Comment: @kas-kad. No, even if you want to, you can't do it. They removed the permanent generation space. My bad, I didn't mentioned it earlier. Perm Gen space they removed and new memory space created named Metaspace. Now this Metaspace is located in Native memory. If you don't define Metaspace size it will exhaust native memory. To do that you can use `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m` switch. Let me know if it works. I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Remember, if you don't want to limit Metaspace size, you can just remove this switch.

Comment: A more important reason for delaying the GC is that a later GC can usually collect more garbage.